# Undefined Symbol when running devtools::check()

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools

I am working on [`markovchain` package](https://github.com/spedygiorgio/markovchain). When development of this package started, functions were not documented using `roxygen2`. Recently, I've updated the documentation of the functions to use `roxygen2`. Note: `NAMESPACE`is not generated by `roxygen2`. It is currently using the old `NAMESPACE` file.

When I ran `devtools::check()`  an error occured !

> Error in dyn.load(dllfile) :    unable to load shared object
>   '/home/deepak/Desktop/gsoc/markovchain/src/markovchain.so':
>   /home/deepak/Desktop/gsoc/markovchain/src/markovchain.so: undefined
>   symbol:
>   _Z14markovchainFitP7SEXPRECN4Rcpp6StringEbidS2_bdNS1_6MatrixILi14ENS1_15PreserveStorageEEE

I have seen other **SO** post where some `.so` files are missing but in my case it is not.

```
    R CMD ldd -r src/markovchain.so

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffed77d000)
    libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f100a3a7000)
    libR.so => /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007f1009d8a000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1009a85000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f100977f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f1009569000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f10091a3000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f1008e89000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f1008c6b000)
    libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f1008a24000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f10087e6000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f10085c4000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f10083b3000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f100819a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f1007f92000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f1007d8d000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f1007b7e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f100abf6000)
    libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f1007941000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f1007718000)
  undefined symbol:   _Z14markovchainFitP7SEXPRECN4Rcpp6StringEbidS2_bdNS1_6MatrixILi14ENS1_15PreserveStorageEEE    (src/markovchain.so)
```

Result of `devtools::build_win()`

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/tmp/Rtmp5Aq9Pf/Rinst7f791b0e862f/markovchain/libs/markovchain.so':
  /tmp/Rtmp5Aq9Pf/Rinst7f791b0e862f/markovchain/libs/markovchain.so: undefined symbol: _Z14markovchainFitP7SEXPRECN4Rcpp6StringEbidS2_bdNS1_6MatrixILi14ENS1_15PreserveStorageEEE
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/tmp/Rtmp5Aq9Pf/Rinst7f791b0e862f/markovchain’
      -----------------------------------
ERROR: package installation failed
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that you will need to do a clean rebuild (e.g. `R CMD INSTALL --preclean --no-multiarch --with-keep.source`)  This is a bit hard to detect solely off of `devtools::check()` could you provide a `devtools::build_win()` output log?

Comment: Also, is this really `Rcpp` related? The use of `R CMD ldd -r` seems to be a standalone job.

Comment: clean rebuild doesn't work. I have added the final result of `devtools::build_win()`

Comment: I want to share one more information. Previously everything was working properly. But when I added a new parameter to existing function. This error arises.

Comment: Well there is your answer: you **must** re-run `compileAttributes()` as clearly explained in the Rcpp Attributes vignette.  RStudio would do it for you tool; it may be your use of the supposedly helpful devtools which trips you up.

Comment: Sir, I have re-run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What can I do to remove this error? Please help. I am stuck on this problem from 2 days. *Not able to add just a new parameter to the existing function.*

Comment: I am working on this package https://github.com/spedygiorgio/markovchain . Is there any way to overcome the issue mentioned in the problem? When devlopment of this package started at that time function were not documented using roxygen2. But now documentation of old function are done using roxygen2. NAMESPACE is not generated by roxygen2. Is old NAMESPACE a problem?

Comment: What is the commit hash or branch this is on?

Comment: master branch and hash 02d9d5c06491e7dde8c64285179d4b125ad62168

Comment: This seems like it is a local issue with your setup as I'm able to easily clone and run the package. What OS are you on? Ubuntu?

Comment: I know it's fine. But the problem is when I tried to add a parameter `sanitize = false` to `markovchainFit` function in *src/1_functions4Fitting.cpp* I am getting the above error?

Comment: My final goal is to add a parameter?

Comment: Please create a dev branch in `markovchain` git repo that includes the problematic code. As is, there is no issue see: http://win-builder.r-project.org/9LLyAvArh4z8

Comment: Hi @Dirk Eddelbuettel, Can you help me now? What I came to know is that when I added a new parameter to other functions then It works fine! But the problem is with one function only? I don't know what is associated with that function.

Comment: You are cordially invited to subscribe to the rcpp-devel list (which is the dedicated Rcpp resource) and ask your problem there.